# How to add an argument to my BaseTest ChromeDriver Instance?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, chromedriver

I have a selenium framework with a BaseTest class. In the BaseTest class we instantiate a ChromeDriver instance which contains various arguments. These are part of the @BeforeMethod (using TestNG). My tests then extend the BaseTest class.

What I want to do for a specific test is to be able to add the --incognito argument to my ChromeDriver instance. How would I go about doing this?

BaseTest code:

```
public class BaseTest {
protected WebDriver driver;

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(Method method) {
    System.out.println("Running " + this.getClass().getName() + "#" + method.getName());
    d = new org.openqa.selenium.Dimension(1350, 660);
    if (browser.equals("firefox")) {
        System.out.println("Reached FF");
        instantiateFirefoxDriver();
    } else if (browser.equals("chrome")) {
        System.out.println("Reached Chrome");
        instantiateChromeDriver();
    } else if (browser.equals("safari")) {
        System.out.println("Reached Safari");
        instantiateSafariDriver();
    }
}

private void instantiateChromeDriver() {
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-plugins");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-extensions");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    this.driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
}

//Some more code......`
```

Example of a Test Class here:

```
public class FinanceScholarshipTest extends BaseTest {

private String financeUserUsername = TestUserConfig.STANDARD_USER_USERNAME;
private String financeUserPassword = TestUserConfig.STANDARD_USER_PASSWORD;
private String financeSecondUsername = TestUserConfig.CURRIC_USER_USERNAME;
private String financeSecondUserPassword = TestUserConfig.CURRIC_USER_PASSWORD;
private String studentNo = "1982076";

private CommonNavigation commonNavigation = new CommonNavigation();
private DataGenerationHelper randomData = new DataGenerationHelper();
private FinanceDBQueries dbQueries = new FinanceDBQueries();

@Test
public void shouldGenerateNewScholarshipForCurrentStudent() throws Exception {
    // Given
    HomePage homePage = commonNavigation.shouldAccessHomepageForSLSTestEnvironment(driver, financeUserUsername, financeUserPassword);
    FinanceHomePage financeHomePage = homePage.clickFinanceLink();
    // When
    ApplicantStudentPage applicantStudentPage = financeHomePage.goToGenrateScholarshipApplicationStudentPage();
    // Then
    assertThat(applicantStudentPage.selectAcademicYear("1")).isEqualTo(applicantStudentPage.getSelectedAcademicYear());
    // Given
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override you `private void instantiateChromeDriver()` method in your child class (you have to **change access modifier of the method in base class in order to do so**) where you can instantiate the driver with the options you need in your child class.

Here is a simple model of your architecture:

Base class with its own initialization

```
public class Base {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(){
        initializeWebDriver();
    }

    protected void initializeWebDriver(){
        System.out.println("Base Initialization");
    }

    @Test
    public void testBase(){
        System.out.println("Test Base");
    }

}
```

Child class with overriden initialization

```
public class Child extends Base{

    @Test
    public void testChild(){
        System.out.println("Test Child");
    }

    @Override
    protected void initializeWebDriver() {
        System.out.println("Child Initialization");
    }
}
```

You can run it as is and then comment overriding in the child class and check how the output changes.

**In your case** I would rework your base class so that you have a separate method that is responsible for building `ChromeOption` and use that method in `instantiateChromeDriver` method. Thus **you could override that new method only** and either call a method from super-class and add one new option in your child class method **or** create new instance of `ChromeOption`and build it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks @wec I'll give this a go in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer (but a lots of maintenance in the future):

1. Create `IncognitoBaseClass` which extends `BaseClass`, override method `instantiateChromeDriver()` and make your TestClasses derive from one of them. As you want them.

Complex answers (one of them might be good):

1. Create different packages for those tests, and use one for IncognitoTests and secon one for normal.
2. **Or** use TestSettings to change the same test to run in different mode.
3. **Or** write using reflections some custom tags, and mark specific tests to use different test settings